# Why do mail signature is being set back if I do not lock file?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, signature

I followed some tutorials and created a HTML signature for Mail Programm. I used my HTML code inside a .mailsignature file, saved the file,checked it as "Locked" and now I'm able to use my signature in mails. Everything works perfect, but I want to able to edit my signature in Mail-Programm. But I cannot edit my signature in Mail programm. I mean if I delete some text or change the text in mail programm it doenst save the signature and I guess its because the .mailsignature file is locked.

But if I unlock signature file, it sets the content to old one. Lets say I create new signature with content "hello world", replace the content in signature file with my HTML content, save the file and re-open mail program, I still see "hello world" and not my new signature content. Is there any work around for that?

My OSX is 10.9.2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have used that way for creating an HTML signature in mail:

1. Create a new signature with a preferred text
2. Full close mail app
3. Go to:  Library ▸ Mail ▸ V2 ▸ MailData
4. Open all files with .mailsignature extension until you find the text that you have writed in the first passage
5. Copy that file in to your desktop
6. Unlock it
7. Put your HTML code
8. Save and lock again that file
9. in Library ▸ Mail ▸ V2 ▸ MailData delete the old file .mailsignature
10. Copy your new .mailsingaturefile with your HTML code

If you don't do that passage mail will replace all .mailsingature files that is no locked or not correspond whit his signature name code.

Comment: Thanks for tutorial I have already done that, but its not the problem in my case.

Comment: Sorry I have just understand now your problem... In fact when you block the .mailsignature file after you can't modify your signature text also in mail program. What you can do is to write you're text and then insert an image html tag for the rest of your signature, for example when you want to insert your company Logo. But in any case when you block the .mailsignature file after there is nothing to do.